# Assigning rank in OpenOffice (or LibreOffice)

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet

In OpenOffice (or LibreOffice), is there a way to rank rows?

For example, let's say you have a spreadsheet where cell A1=20, A2=30, and A3=10.

I want to B1 to get a value of 2, B2 to get a value of 3, and B3 to get a value of 1.  This ranks them from smallest to largest.

If the values in A1, A2, or A3 change, I want the rank to automatically update.

I would prefer not to use macros, and would like this to work for an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for catching that.  I had multiple errors.  My apologies.  I fixed the errors, and added a clarification.  Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Hmmm... SMALL looks interesting, but I want something similar to the inverse of it: I want the cell to be filled with the second parameter (the index, or as I called it, the *rank*).

Comment: @fixer1234 That could work.  Are you thinking create a temporary table in another worksheet?

Comment: It turns out there's a built-in RANK function in LO Calc.  You're in business.  Just start entering the function and click the wizard.

Comment: @fixer1234 What? That wasn't there 4 hours ago! ;-)  Thanks so much... I'll report back if it works (and it looks like it will).

Comment: @fixer1234 It looks like RANK.EQ may work, but it appears to be buggy.  I have to press Ctrl+Shift+F9 to force a recalc every time a value changes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RANK.EQ.  It should be as simple as (for B1): =RANK(A1,A1:A3,1) (parameters: value, array, type: 0/missing=descending; other=ascending)

Comment: @fixer1234 RANK.EQ is the same as RANK.  They just renamed RANK when they added RANK.AVG.  RANK still works for backwards compatibility.  I've found at least 2 significant bugs in LibreOffice just in these functions though.

Comment: @fixer1234   Do you experience the manual refresh requirement (to get ranks to adjust when the data changes)?

Comment: Just tried it with RANK and there was no refresh problem.  I changed the 30 to 15.  As soon as I hit enter, the ranks changed (correctly).  Changed it back and it worked again.  Tried changing it to RANK.EQ and it didn't recognize the function.  I use Debian and the software in the repo tend to be old.  This is an older version of Calc.

Comment: @fixer1234 Sounds like another regression bug in LibreOffice.  I find at least 2 of them every time I use it.  I still sometimes report them, but they rarely get fixed.  I used to report all of them, but some of the egos/attitudes at LibreOffice are atrocious.

Comment: What happens if you use RANK instead of RANK.EQ?

Comment: Oh no, these LibreOffice bugs are rarely simple.  RANK and RANK.EQ both have the refresh bug.  But it's not that simple (naturally).  If I create a new spreadsheet, the identical functions work as expected.  Copy those functions into a complex spreadsheet, and they break.

Comment: So I have something to look forward to when Debian finally updates to a now-current version of LO (at which point that version will be ancient).  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32658/discussion-between-fixer1234-and-rockpaperlizard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it in LO Calc to verify that it works:

[image: screenshot]

The RANK function will rank either ascending or descending (last parameter zero or missing =descending, any other value = ascending).  So B1 would be:

```
=RANK(A1,A$1:A$3,1)
```

Syntax: RANK(value, array, type)

Comment: Thanks!  Note that recent versions of LibreOffice have a bug in which RANK will not get automatically updated in complex spreadsheets.  The user has to manually refresh all data each time they want the ranks to be updated.  They work as expected in an empty spreadsheet, but when used in new ones, they do not work as expected.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: It just occurred to me that the recalculation issue you're seeing with RANK might be due to a problem with your LO Calc installation, itself, rather than a bug with the function.  What you described in chat sounds like LO might have become corrupted.  If you reinstall LO and the "bug" disappears, it would be useful to post another comment so people don't unnecessarily shy away from using the function.

Comment: I'll do just that.  I'll also clear the profile.

Comment: I have tried multiple versions of LibreOffice, and it's been years since I've seen such a buggy application.  Each version I tried had different obvious bugs.  I think I may have to go back to recommending OpenOffice.  LibreOffice is just too buggy.